# Power Bi URL Filter always showing all

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a power bi report that I am trying to embed in a webpage. I currently have my URL as `"https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=<reportId>&autoAuth=true&filter=<tableName>/<columnName> eq '<stringValue>'"`

When i got to the webpage, it shows the filter, but states it is filtering `columnName is (All)` regardless of what I enter as the column value. The data is being pulled from an azure sql database through direct query.

I started out using the syntax described on the microsoft docs `?filter=` instead of `&filter=` but changed to & after the filter wasn't showing up at all and reading https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues/588